# A word to describe someone who isn't easily fooled or deceived?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

Whats a good word to describe someone who isn't easily fooled or isn't gullible?

Comment: I think the proper word is going to be based on the threshold of "easiness" to fool. For example "astute" would be a good fit for describing someone who doesn't go along with the idea that ostriches hide their head underground. While, skeptical, is based more in doubting as a default position on a topic. Skeptical about our effect on global warming for example. There are other examples of "common sense" or awareness, but they all seem be based on situations and circumstances.

Comment: I tried to look up antonyms of "gullible" but found that word isn't in the dictionary.

Answer (score 16):

Perhaps you can use *[shrewd](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/shrewd)* or *[astute](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/astute)*. *[Wary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/wary?showCookiePolicy=true)* may be also a good fit.

Comment: also "distrustful" or "cautious"

Comment: also also "discerning"

Answer (score 7):

In the US, we call a person who is quick to "see through" others, ***"street-smart"***. While the expression can be used in other ways, it is often a way to describe someone who is not easily deceived.

Answer (score 5):

Canny.

1.
having or showing shrewdness and good judgment, especially in money or business matters
"canny shoppers came early for a bargain"
synonyms:
shrewd, astute, smart, sharp, sharp-witted, ... more

Answer (score 4):

I would expect that a [*savvy*](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3Asavvy) person would not be gullible and would be difficult to fool.

Answer (score 3):

In common use, one might call someone who's very on-guard against being tricked *suspicious*.  This sense of the word is defined by [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/suspicious) as "having or showing a feeling that something is wrong or that someone is behaving wrongly : feeling or showing suspicion".  Note that this word can be applied *both* to the person who suspects something and to the person or thing that they suspect.

Another, perhaps less confrontational, way to describe this person *skeptical*, which is defined by [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/skeptical) "as having or expressing doubt about something (such as a claim or statement)".

Answer (score 2):

What about a [*skeptic*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/skeptic)?

> noun skep·tic \ˈskep-tik\ : a person who questions or doubts something
>   (such as a claim or statement) : a person who often questions or
>   doubts things

Skeptics are usually hard to fool or deceive, as they tend to be doubtful until evidence or something shows otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

[*wise*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/wise) - the definition given by Collins includes shrewd, suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

Along with the other suggestions, *keen* and *perceptive* also fit.

Answer (score 0):

Although not specific to being difficult to fool, the word *sharp* comes to mind.

> You won’t fool Charlie, he's a sharp one.

From the [Oxford dictionaries online definition of *sharp*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sharp) -

> Having or showing speed of perception, comprehension, or response: